# How to disable the radio button for a fixed interval of time after clicking them?

Tags: javascript, html

Hi guys,

```
    <input type="radio" value="LIKE" onclick="func(this.value)">LIKE
    <br>
    <input type="radio" value="OK" onclick="func(this.value)">OK
    <br>
    <input type="radio" value="DISLIKE" onclick="func(this.value)">DISLIKE
    <br>
```

I want to disable all the radio buttons when one of it is clicked and then to enable it after a fixed interval of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example how you could do it if you don't mind using jQuery. You can use the HTML attribute [disabled](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_radio_disabled.asp%20'disabled') to disable the radios when they are clicked and then use [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp%20'setTimeout();') to enable them again after a set amount of time. Below time is set to 3000 milliseconds.

```
$('document').ready( function() {
    $('input').on('click', function(){
        $('input').attr('disabled',true);

        setTimeout(function() {
            $('input').attr('disabled',false);
        }, 3000);
    });    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0912shz0/1/

Answer (score 1):

You could try code like:-

```
$('#like, #unlike, #dislike').click(function(){
        $("#like, #unlike, #dislike").attr("disabled",true);

   setTimeout(function(){
        $("#like, #unlike, #dislike").attr("disabled",false);
   },2000);
})
```

HTML

```
 <input type="radio" value="LIKE" id="like" >LIKE
 <input type="radio" value="OK"  id="unlike">OK
 <input type="radio" value="DISLIKE" id="dislike">DISLIKE
```

[DEMO here (JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/9ek875xm/3/)

Comment: Why use document.getElementById when you've wrapped it in jQuery and have $(this) for the #like element?

Comment: yeah.code will go like that only. I jst replied in hurry and mixed Javscpt wid jQuery..I Will update my fiddle :)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a timer, using **setTimeout**:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout

And in the body of the function you would need to know how to use the **disabled** attribute in javascript:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/disabled

And you would not need to pass **this.value** to the function, what you would need is **this** - which would be the element you want to disable, or **event** - the event which contains the element at **event.target**. Note: if you pass the **event** parameter you would need to use cross-browser code so that it works in different browsers. For example:

```
function(event) {
    //short-hand for: if(event) event=event; else event=window.event;
    event = event || window.event; 
    // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
     $(this).attr('disabled', true);

     setTimeout(function() {
          $('input[type="radio"]').attr('disabled', false);
    }, /*time interval in ms*/)
});
```

not tested, written from head

Comment: You could store $(this) in a variable, ex: `var radioBtn = $(this);` and also your 2nd use of it would return a collection if there are more than one radio buttons on the page.

Comment: yes, that's true. You can use some additional class info, ex `$('input.someclass')`

Answer (score 0):

Working for me

```
    <script>
    function func(thisValue){
        setTimeout(function() {
          $('input[type=radio]').attr("disabled",true);
           $('input[type=radio]').removeAttr("checked");

           $('input[value='+thisValue+']').attr("disabled",false);
           $('input[value='+thisValue+']').attr("checked","checked");
           $('input[value='+thisValue+']').prop('checked', true);

        }, 100);
    }
    </script>
```

HTML

```
    <label onclick="func('LIKE')" style="position:relative"><input type="radio" value="LIKE" >LIKE</label>
    <label onclick="func('DISLIKE')" style="position:relative"><input type="radio" value="DISLIKE">DISLIKE</label>
```